# Removing the subdomain as a subdirectory in Apache

Tags: domains, subdomain, apache2

I simply trying to make my webpage come up as `owncloud.example.com` instead of `owncloud.example.com/owncloud`.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and Apache 2.4, and using OpenSSL. I have tried changing things in my *apache.conf* and *conf-available*, and I have changed the root directory to `/var/www/` and put the first one in there without any luck.

Comment: Please show your configuration files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical way to host a new domain or subdomain under Ubuntu/Debian is covered in [this tutorial](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/412).  Here are the basic steps:

1. Create the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/owncloud.example.com.conf` with contents based on this template:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *>
           ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
           ServerName  owncloud.example.com
           DirectoryIndex index.html
           DocumentRoot /home/www/owncloud.example.com/htdocs/                
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
2. Put your *index.html* and other files into `/home/www/owncloud.example.com/htdocs/`
3. Run the command `sudo a2ensite owncloud.example.com` to enable the configuration for the site
4. Run the command `sudo service apache2 restart` to restart the web server